# How to match any whitespace in body of mail in procmail?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, procmail

I tried to use such rule:

```
:0 B
* Something[[:space:]]+whatever
```

but it doesn't work.

When I change [[:space:]] to literal space character:

```
:0 B
* Something +whatever
```

it works.

It also works in case of:

```
:0 B
* Something[ ]+whatever
```

I must be doing something wrong, but can't really find it. Any hints?

Comment: Well, it looks like procmail does not support the posix class `[[:space:]]`. How come you think it does? Does it say in the manual that it should support it? I'm not being a smart @ss, I am unfamiliar with procmail, so I rally don't know. But is sure looks like it isn't supported.

Comment: Manual says that procmail uses egrep for filtering - to be specific - flag "B" is: `B    Egrep the body.`. and egrep does support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just adding the white space characters in a class you want to match:

```
[ \t\r\n]
```

matches a space, tab, carriage return and line feed.

There are of course more white space chars, but these are the most commonly used.

Comment: While technically possible, I'd rather use standard class for readability reasons.